# RxJS: Disable refresh button for duration after clicked

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I am new to RxJS and tried to do a simple demo that lets you refresh the data every one second.

I made a button and created a click stream from it.
The problem started when i wanted to make a stream that every button click emits false and after one second emits true once again.

For example - the initial state is true as we can refresh at start.
Once i clicked the button the new value should be false right after the click as we cant refresh further.

Lastly after one second passed - the value should be true once again.

I tried creating it and succeeded, but it looks terrible. 
Any ideas hot to do it better and cleaner? 
Another thing is I don't really know if it is even a good idea to use RxJS here as the easy regular way is to have a Boolean set to true and after I clicked set it to false and with setTimeout change it back to true.

Here is what i did:

```
// The stream of the button clicks.
$clicksStream
  // Change the click stream to the timed true false change.
  .switchMap(() => Observable
                    // Emit first value immediately and every 1 second after.
                    .timer(0, 1000)
                    // Map each one - 0 becomes false and others true.
                    .map(x => !!x)
                    // Take only first two items.
                    .take(2))
  // Always the start value is true.
  .startWith(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling async operations with `rxjs` is an excellent idea. It's what reactive programming is about and `rxjs` is good at doing it.

The beauty of the code you have produced is that it is pure. It doesn't depend on any external context.

Using the `setTimeout` and the good ol' boolean to change state will work of course but at the price of purity and functional programming. You would be doing imperative programming and side effects. And the semantic of the code wouldn't be the same

```
button.addEventListener("click", function refresh(event) {
  refreshData();
  setTimeout(renderButton, 1000, true)
  renderButton(false)
})
```

The problem with that piece of code: **it is very dependant on its context**. For it to work you need to implement `refreshData` and `renderButton`. They also need to be accessible from that scope.

But you piece of code was totally standalone, you could copy/paste it elsewhere, it would still work.

The other problem is that the click handler function is responsible for way too many things (actually refreshing the data, rendering the new state of the button and launching the timeout. It's totally **breaking the Single Responsibility Principle**.

I hope I have helped you seeing the benefits of the code you have produced. It's actually pretty good, it's just a matter of getting used to it.

One simple simplification you could make would be using `startWith` and `mapTo` instead of the kind-of-hacky `!!x` :)

```
$clicksStream
  // Change the click stream to the timed true false change.
  .switchMap(() => Observable
                    // just a timer of 1000ms
                    .timer(1000)
                    // when it emits we just return true
                    .mapTo(true)
                    // Take only first two items.
                    .startWith(false)
  )
  // Always the start value is true.
  .startWith(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`timeoutWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeoutWith) operator to do this.

```
$clickStream
  .switchMapTo(
    // Start with false
    Observable.of(false)
      // If no values are emitted for 1 second emit true
      .timeoutWith(1000, Observable.of(true))
  )
  .startWith(true);
```